# Click events in jquery / ajax removing existing append

Tags: jquery, ajax, select, click, append

I'm having trouble with page refreshes following jquery click events.

The following is loaded via ajax so not present on initial page load.

I'm also using ajax to get a json array to add to the selects.

When one of the click events is fired, all works fine, but if the other button is clicked, the appended options to the first select disappear and it returns to the pre-appended state.

All of the inputs are outside of a form.

```
<select name="frombox" id="frombox" form="newjob_form">
<option value="1">cats</option>
<option value="2">dogs</option>
<option value="3">mice</option>
</select>

<select name="tobox" id="tobox" form="newjob_form">
<option value="1">cats</option>
<option value="2">dogs</option>
<option value="3">mice</option>
</select>


<input id="showallfav" name="showallfav" onclick="return false" title="All Favourites" type="button"  class="showallfav" />

<input id="showallfavto" name="showallfavto" onclick="return false" title="All Favourites" type="button"   class="showallfav" />

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

        var toAppendto = "";
        var toAppend = "";


    $(function () {


        $(document).on("click", "#showallfav", function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation(); 
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajaxallfav.php",
                async: false,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data){
                    $.each(data, function () {
                        toAppend += "<option value=" + this.oV + ">" + this.oD + "</option>";
                    });
                         return false;
                }
            });
            $("#frombox").append(toAppend);
               return false;
        });

        $("#showallfavto").live('click', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation(); 
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "ajaxallfav.php",
                async: false,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    $.each(data, function () {
                        toAppendto += "<option value=" + this.oV + ">" + this.oD + "</option>";
                    });
                         return false;
                }

            });
            $("#tobox").append(toAppendto);
               return false;
                event.preventDefault(); 
        });
    });
    </script>
```

---

All thoughts appreciated!

I've tried to set up a jsfiddle but struggling to replicate the ajax return from ajaxallfav.php !

Thanks in advance,
Steve

Answer (score 0):

Try to reset the `toAppendTo` variable before adding new ones.. like:

```
..
success: function (data) {
   toAppendto = ""; // Add this.
   $.each(data, function () {
     toAppendto += "<option value=" + this.oV + ">" + this.oD + "</option>";
   });
   return false;
}
..
```